# Why does order and way of calling goroutines matter?

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to understand goroutines.
In the following example, why do 1)--4)  behave differently?
See https://play.golang.org/p/_XXZe47W53v

```
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func send(x int, ch chan int) {ch<-x}
func read(ch chan int) {fmt.Println(<-ch)}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)

    go read(ch)              // 1) works
    go send(1,ch)            // -> 1

    // go fmt.Println(<-ch)  // 2) fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
    // go send(1,ch)         // isn't this the same as the above ?

    // go send(1,ch)         // 3) works
    // go fmt.Println(<-ch)  // -> 1

    // go fmt.Println(<-ch)  // 4) fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
    // go send(1,ch)         // why does the order of the go routine calls matter?

    time.Sleep(100*time.Millisecond)
}
```

Comment: ["evaluation of f, x, y, and z happens in the current goroutine"](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing the errors because the read is not happening inside of the goroutine, but in the main thread.

The line:

```
go fmt.Println(<-ch)
```

is evaluating the parameter in the main thread, and once it succeeds it will run the `Println` in the goroutine with the already resolved parameter. Since the code can never write to the `ch` in this state, it deadlocks.

You can observe this by changing it to:

```
go func() { fmt.Println(<-ch) }()
```

Then it will create a closure around the `ch`, and then the anonymous routine will be blocked, not the main thread, which can continue on to the `send()`.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! Now I got the meaning of "evaluation of f, x, y, and z happens in the current goroutine"